# Move PageFile.sys To Another Drive

Tags: windows, pagefile

Is it 100% safe to move the pagefile.sys file from c: to another drive on Windows Server 2008?  We are getting low on C: space and need to move it off, but not if there is any risk.  This is a production web server and (other than a quick reboot) downtime is not acceptable, as you can imagine :)

Comment: StackOverflow is for developer and programming questions. You'll have better luck posting this to the SeverFault list. http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is a good place for such questions, its a programming related site,

I can give you a hint that this should be OK, It will even speed up you paging file, some reference below (I was actually reading it recently :) ):

http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it

following part:

> What you should actually do is move your pagefile to a completely
>   different physical drive to split up the workload.

but confirm it with some windows admin experts